# How to add documentation for required query parameters?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to create a fastapi API endpoint that relies on HTTP GET parameters, has them documented and uses fastapi's validation capabilities. Consider the following minimal example:

```
import fastapi

app = fastapi.FastAPI(
)

@app.get("/endpoint")
def example_endpoint(
    par1: int = fastapi.Query(
        None,
        description="example documentation1",
    ),

    par2: int = fastapi.Query(
        None,
        description="example documentation2",
    ),
):
    return {"test": par1 + par2}
```

This has the documentation support and works over HTTP GET parameters, but doesn't validate them - http://localhost:8000/endpoint?par1=2&par2=3 works fine, but http://localhost:8000/endpoint crashes with an internal server error, instead of notifying the user that a parameter was expected. Is there a way to make par1 and par2 required and keep the documentation feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis), If you hadn't seen that `...` before: it is a special single value that makes query **required**

```
from fastapi import Query

Query(...,description="example documentation1")
```

So in your case answer below can do the job

```
@app.get("/endpoint")
def example_endpoint(
    par1: int = fastapi.Query(..., description="example documentation1",),
    par2: int = fastapi.Query(..., description="example documentation2",),
):

    if par1 and par2:
        return {"test": par1 + par2}

    raise ValueError("Missing query parameters")
```

Also you can use **`example=1`**

```
Query(..., description="example documentation2", example=1)
```

Comment: What is  the `example=1` in `Query(...)` ?

Comment: It's a great question. Simply it adds example value like default, that query will be 1 if it's empty, kinda like when you open the Body of an **POST** endpoint there will be the same example values by default, for str there will be "string", for int there will be 0 etc.

Comment: But it's just an example when you send a request to the `/endpoint` without any query parameter's you 'll be still getting an error `{"detail":[{"loc":["query","par1"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}`